# How to declare and accept parameters in a grails 3.0 create-script

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Using the create-script Grails creates a Gant script.
I've seen that through argsMap I have access to the input parameters. e.g.

```
grails run my-script --parameter1=value1 --parameter2=value2
```

I can access parameters like this:

```
argsMap.parameter1 == value1
argsMap.parameter2 == value2
```

How can I make a script that only accepts one domain class as parameter without the need to specify --parameterName. eg

```
grails my-script foo.MyDomainClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Javadoc of `GroovyScriptCommand` (see that [link](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/api/org/grails/cli/profile/commands/script/GroovyScriptCommand.html#getArgs())) you can use the `args` list instead of the `argsMap`.

Simply use `args[0]` in your script instead of a named parameter.